# Can't understand how to use Drive API

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to implement Google Drive functionality in our application and in stuck with such problem: using this code

```
try {
    // File's binary content
    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/miniclipId.txt");
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

    // File's metadata.
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
    body.setMimeType("text/plain");

    FileList file = service.files().list().execute();
    if (file != null) {
        //showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
        //startCameraIntent();
    }
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
      startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
} catch (IOException e) {
      showToast(e.getMessage());
}
```

i'm trying to send simple text file to Google drive and, such a bad luck, i get this    exeption:

```
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "message": "Access Not Configured",
      "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
}
```

I enabled Drive API in google API Console, entered SHA1 debug fingerprint and app's package name is exactly the same as entered in API Console.
Any ideas please?

Comment: A lot of dead code sorry. The query is FileList file = service.files().list().execute();. As is in an example on google drive api page.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the same error 2 months ago. My problem was the .android folder had some corrupt data (keystore I supouse) so I copied the folder from another PC where I was developing and solve it.
Maybe it helps... anyway, if you don't have a backup of that folder, I would create the keystore again and enter the new certificate SHA1 in the API console.
See [google drive api error 403 Access Not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731196/google-drive-api-error-403-access-not-configured)

Answer (score 0):

Just Register your application aagain or delete the old Oauth Id and create a new one and you will not this error again:
https://cloud.google.com/console#/project

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gs-discussion/9Ri4AwdHqDg