# google drive api access not configured

Tags: google-drive-api

I am following the google drive android quick start sdk [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android). The only difference is that I am using intellij instead of eclipse.

The app throws an exception when uploading the file:

```
File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

The exception message is `access not configured`.

Now googling this error yields some results:

- [google drive api error 403 Access Not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731196/google-drive-api-error-403-access-not-configured)
- [Google Drive HTTP 403 "Access Not Configured" error with DrEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368678/google-drive-http-403-access-not-configured-error-with-dredit)

I have checked in the google cloud console that both the drive api & the drive sdk are activated. I have registered an app with the correct package name. I also added google cloud storage just in case. What else should I check?

**Edit**

I am really confused by the documentation. [This page](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html) mentions the `getToken` method, but the sample application uses `GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2` which documentation [is](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.12.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential.html) `Constructor a new instance using OAuth 2.0 scopes`.

When registering the application, I get some information like client secret/client ID. I could find information [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials) explaining how to use this data, but I could not find this kind of example for an android app.

Answer (score 0):

In the API Console, when you register/create an app, a Client ID is generated. Have you coded that Client ID into your app? The answer to the first SO link you gave has details.

Comment: `Have you coded that Client ID into your app?`I have looked very hard at the documentation, but I could not find any place where to use this client ID.